# Get total and remaining space on a directory along with size of all directories inside

Tags: bash, shell

I have come up with a single line script which gives file sizes as below. I am trying to find a way to show me total disk space along with remaining space on the directory.

```
du -sh * | sort -hr

12G     lithium
11G     sodium
160M    soking
```

expecting something to be like below(free and total are rough numbers). It doesn't need to be in this way , but I am looking all the values in two columns. I am exporting this data to upstream app.

```
12G     lithium
11G     sodium
160M    soking
55G     total space
22G     free space
```

thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by _remaining space **on a directory**_? Meaningful would be _remaining space **on a disk**_.

Comment: Yeah, I have a directory called `"/apps/newone" `. The actual size is of `/apps` mount is 89G , under that most consuming directory is `newone`. under newone there are multiple directories which I am interesting in calculating consumed space and left space on `/apps` mount. 

`12G     lithium
11G     sodium
16G    soking
39G     total space
49G     free space`

Comment: if you see the total space is 89G and the three directories lithium, sodium and soking under newone consumed space of 39G, which is what showed under `total space` . so the remaining is 50G , among that 1G is utilized by other directories under `/apps` so the free space is showing as `49G`. Hope I explained in detail here.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -v fs="/" 'NR==FNR { print;if ($6==fs) { tot=$2;avail=$3 } next} END { printf "%s\ttotal space\n",tot; printf "%s\tfree space\n",avail; }' <(du -sh * | sort -hr) <(df -h)
```

Redirect the output of du -sh * | sort -hr and df -h back into awk. Pass the file system the directory in question is mounted on to awk as a variable fs. For the first input (NR==FNR), awk just prints the line and skips to the next line. Awk then checks to see if the 6th space delimited field is equal to fs and if it is, it tracks the total and available space through variables tot and avail respectively. At the end of processing both inputs, the tot and avail variables are printed in the format required.

Comment: I have tried the command as is , with `fs="/"` and I see output as the way I mentioned, but the space is something not correct as

`74G     total space
9%      free space`

the total space consumed is not adding up and free is coming in percent. possible to get as a value in size?

what I have done is modified the `fs="/apps/newone/"` , surprisingly I have empty values. 

`
        total space
        free space
`

unable to format properly because of empty spaces.

Comment: I've amended the answer

Comment: I have tried and I still get same empty values. I must be missing something it seems .

Comment: could you be able to help me here?
@Raman Sailopal

Comment: Can you post the output of the df and du commands?

Comment: sorry, the command is generating huge output on my server. can you share on what you are looking. Thank you for your response.